# How to pass Maven compiler args via environment variable?

Tags: maven, stack-overflow, lombok

I have the issue that my `mvn compile` fails on an internal project for some reason. Two other colleagues tried it as well and it does not fail on their machines.
We use Lombok there (I am not a fan but that was not my choice) and for some reason it fails with a `StackOverflowError`. After some research I found a solution, adding:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-J-Xss4M</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This works fine, but I'd like not to change the *pom.xml* if this only happens on my machine. So is there a way to add the `Xss` flag to some environment variable?

I tried to add it via MAVEN_OPTS, in Windows as well as in IntelliJ -> Maven Runner Settings, with and without `-J`in front, but it fails as before.

Comment: The first thing I would request to find why it fails only on a single machine... different  JDK version ? etc. ? And no it's not possible to do so...

Comment: I have OpenJDK 1.8.0_212, they have 1.8.0_201. Those are managed machines, I have no way of installing something on it, so this does not matter to me. I want to find a way to increase the stack size without changing the project code.

Comment: @ctwx If it fails on one machine but not the other, you need to find out why, not build around it.

Comment: As @JFabianMeier you must find the root cause anything else will cause more issues in the future...already giving a compiler arg with defining the stack size is very strange...Second if there is a stackoverflow there is a stack trace which should give you at least a hint....

Comment: I fully agree, but the issue is that I only have 5 days left in that company and this is a managed machine. The company I work for has a few thousand employees and the IT department is very restrictive. So, I have no way of fixing it in 5 days. Thanks though.

Comment: I guess, having something similar to the `maven.compiler.*` properties for that would be handy.